# incoming email is rejected

Tags: postfix, smtp

I have built a mail server using ubuntu LTS 16.04 , postfix, dovecot, and mysql. There are several errors when there is an email sent to my server.

When I check `/var/log/mail.log`, these are the errors:

```
Sep  8 07:12:50 mail postfix/smtpd[5269]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-yw0-f169.google.com[209.85.161.169]: 454 4.7.1 <hari@bandungtalentsource.com>: Relay access denied; from=<kantorqu28@gmail.com> to=<hari@bandungtalentsource.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-yw0-f169.google.com>

Sep  8 07:12:51 mail postfix/smtpd[5269]: disconnect from mail-yw0-f169.google.com[209.85.161.169] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 data=0/1 quit=1 commands=5/7
```

Here is my `postconf -n`:

[image]

In this case, I have not yet implemented sasl authentication, spamassasin, clamav, or Amavis.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Add your domain (bandungtalentsource.com) in `mydestination` or add `relay_domains = bandungtalentsource.com`, restart postfix and try again.